# Azure Service Bus - 401 40103: Invalid authorization token signature for post message using CURL

Tags: azure, authentication, curl, azureservicebus

I see Authorization failure while posting a message to a queue I created in Azure Service bus using CURL

Command:
curl -v -X POST -H 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sig=58ecf57a25352fb4506f6a934bace10eeac4dae8eaf578093b8161af949b7ef4&se=1543536196&skn=test&sr=https%3A%2F%2Fndasns.servicebus.windows.net%2Fasbqueue' -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.microsoft.servicebus.yml' https://ndasns.servicebus.windows.net/asbqueue/messages -d '[{"body":"m1"}]'

namesapce name: ndasns
queue name: asbqueue

I used 
https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output
to create signature of my resource uri using secretkey, resource uri and token expiration time. Below captures the input i provided.

https://ndasns.servicebus.windows.net/+"\n"+1543536196

I chose token expiry time as some time of 30th November 2018

I have created a new shared access policy for my queue called test which has all three: send, receive, Manage rules enabled.

The output of the CURL command is as shown below:
HTTP/1.1 401 40103: Invalid authorization token signature

I followed below link to frame my sendMessage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-batch
and below link to create SAS token
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas

Is there any way I could debug this error further?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the content of the `sr` parameter (namespace) of the **Authorization** header to just **ndasns** instead of **https%3A%2F%2Fndasns.servicebus.windows.net%2Fasbqueue** might solve the problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried with just ndasns for sr parameter. But still seeing the same error.

Comment: You used SHA256 when you generated the signature?